# ffmpeg hw accel sample code or tutorials?

Tags: ffmpeg

I had wrote a video player based ffmpeg, now it is working fine. but high CPU usage up to 60% when decoding some 1080p video files, such as wmv/rmvb/mkv formats (my config: I5,8G,HD7850).

after do many searchs, I know the "hw accel", and I found the ffplay.c has enabled it. But the source code of ffplay.c is too large and too complex to read, who had simple code can teach this?

PS: I found some codes of DXVA2 for ffmpeg, add it to my project and build ok. I debug it, no problem, working fine, but the CPU usage only a few decrease, about 10%...

Comment: Interested in this myself, also for encoding.